# SQL Server : select range from x to y from a temp result without ordering column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a real exotic situation with my SQL Server database and been searching since yesterday... but I gotta give up now.

I have a

- `Document` table (`DocumentID (PK), ArchiveNo`, etc...)

and a

- `LanguageVersion` table (`LanguageVersionID (PK), LanguageVersionID (FK), ReleaseDate, Language`, etc...) which has a n:1 relation to `Document` (1 Document has (n) LanguageVersions).

After a user search I already have a list of `Document` that the user is allowed to see.
These have to be sorted by `ReleaseDate`, which is located in the `LanguageVersion` table.

So I joined `LanguageVersion` to it, naturally resulting in duplication of `Document` entries, sorted this result by `ReleaseDate` and cut off everything else than the `DocumentID`.

Ok - so far I got a list of `DocumentID`'s in the right order, but with duplicates.

Now for displaying the result, the requirement is to group these results by pages of 20 !!Documents!!. Therefore I found 2 possible solutions: either the `ROW_NUMBER()-OVER()` clause or in SQL Server 2012 there is the new extension of the `ORDER-BY` clause with `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT`.

The problem is, that both of these need an ordering column to generate the row numbers as base for the range selection.

- If I keep the `ReleaseDate` in my temporary result for this ordering, the distinction of `DocumentID`'s fails because every duplicate of a `DocumentID` has different `ReleaseDates`.
- If I cut off the `ReleaseDate`, I can do the `DISTINCT` but lose the ordering column for generating the range index.

I'm quite frustrated, because I'm used to MySQL where there's no problem using the `LIMIT` clause just without any ordering.

Isn't there any equivalent in SQL Server?

I already have the document result in the right order, the only problem is the duplication.
All I want is: `DISTINCT` on `DocumentID`'s and then select a range from x to y from that.

Regards and thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: So given one `DocumentID` that has 5 `LanguageVersion` with different `ReleaseDate` values - **which one** of those 5 release dates do you want to keep and use and display? Either you want to show all five - then you already have the solution - or you need to decide which one of the language versions is the "master" to be shown. With the current info you're giving us, this cannot be decided ...

Comment: yep, right - i need to show one of them as 'master' but this is a decision that is more complex and needs to be made by the program logic. All i just need is 20 documents out of my temporary result in the right order - the rest will be made later :)
And thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: The problem is the duplication in my temporary result. I can EITHER distinct duplicates (by cutting off the ReleaseDate before) OR use OFFSET / FETCH NEXT by ordering by ReleaseDate. I need both... i want to distinct duplicates of DocumentID's and then (in the reduced result) fetch 20 rows. If I fetch 20 rows from the temp result i'd only get about 7-10 single Documents, duplicated to 20 in total.

Answer (score 0):

Given your setup, you can do something like this:

- create a CTE (Common Table Expression) to select a *page* of `DocumentID` - 10, 20 at a time - whatever works for you. This gives you the ability to specify how many and which `DocumentID` values you want
- join that CTE (limited to the page of 20 `DocumentID` you want) with the `LanguageVersion` table, to get the full set of data you want

This gives you what you want: define and get exactly n `DocumentID`'s (for paging), plus all the additional details from the `LanguageVersion` table.

So try this :

```
-- define the CTE, give it a name
;WITH DocumentPage AS
(
    -- define the rows to fetch - here, I'm using the ROW_NUMBER approach 
    SELECT 
        DocumentID ,
        ArchiveNo,
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DocumentID)
    FROM dbo.Document
)
-- define the full query - get everything from the "paged" DocumentPage CTE,
-- plus the relevant details from the LanguageVersion table
SELECT  
    dp.DocumentID ,
    dp.ArchiveNo,
    lv.LanguageVersionID ,
    lv.ReleaseDate ,
    lv.Language
FROM 
    DocumentPage dp
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.LanguageVersion lv ON dp.DocumentID = lv.DocumentID
WHERE 
    dp.RowNum BETWEEN 51 AND 60 -- define which rows from the Document table you want
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately this answer didn't solve my problem, but it pushed me to realizing that my whole concept was wrong. The problem here was, that i could not order the RowNum by DocumentID, because this would've changed the order by the primary order criteria ReleaseDate. But your answer was ok for understanding the ROW_NUMBER()/OVER() clause ;)